# Error code -2130575338 library office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.runtime.http.request_options import RequestOptions
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file    import File
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext("https://infarmahonduras.sharepoint.com/sites/ContabilidadInfarma")   
ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user("xxxxxxxx","xxxxxxx")   
ctx = ClientContext("https://infarmahonduras.sharepoint.com/sites/ContabilidadInfarma", ctx_auth)
relative_url= "/sites/ContabilidadInfarma/Documents/Mercadeo202005.xlsx"
filename = 'Mercadeo202005.xlsx'
with open(filename, 'wb') as output_file:
    response = File.open_binary(ctx, relative_url)
    output_file.write(response.content)
print(response.content)**
```

#I have the problem that it downloads the file but it is not more than 1 kb and the original file size is 189 kb when changing the extension to XLS the following error is written

{"error":{"code":"-2130575338, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"es-ES","value":"El archivo /sites/ContabilidadInfarma/Documents/Mercadeo202005.xlsx no existe."}}}'

Answer (score 0):

@FernandoGFMC,

I tested your code on my SPO environment, here it works well. From the error msg, it seems that the relative_url of the file is not correct.

If your file is in the default library, the ServerRelativeUrl should be:

```
/sites/{site}/Shared Documents/{filename}.xlsx
```

'Documents' is the list name while Shared Documents is the root folder. In fact, I am able to produce the error if I set a wrong URL:

[image]

BR